# Need to reformat text file moving speaker text up a line to speaker label

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have a number of .txt files with text that I need to reformat. Specifically, I have Speaker A and Speaker B and the text is on the subsequent line.

```
A:
I can not believe the weather today .
B:
It is beautiful outside .
A:
Really nice .
B:
Okay , how are you doing ?
A:
I am good .
B:
Good to hear .
A:
Thank you .
```

It is possible to have more speakers but all would have : before their label.

I'd like the file output to read:

```
A: I can not believe the weather today .
B: It is beautiful outside .
A: Really nice .
B: Okay , how are you doing ?
A: I am good .
B: Good to hear .
A: Thank you .
```

Thank you.

Edit:

Also, is there a solution if there are multiple lines of text in between speaker labels? For example:

```
A:
Well hello . 
Long time no see . 
How are you doing ? 
B:
Good . 
How are you ?
A:
Really great .
B:
Good .
```

With the expected outcome...

```
A: Well hello . Long time no see . How are you doing ? 
B: Good . How are you ?
A: Really great .
B: Good .
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex substitution can handle this:

```
import re

text = """A:
I can not believe the weather today .
B:
It is beautiful outside ."""

text = re.sub(r"^(\w+:)\s*", r"\1 ", text, flags=re.MULTILINE)

print(text)

# A: I can not believe the weather today .
# B: It is beautiful outside .
```

#### EDIT:

Based on the updated question, for multiline dialogue:

```
import re

text = """A:
Well hello . 
Long time no see . 
How are you doing ? 
B:
Good . 
How are you ?"""

text = re.sub(r"(.*?)\s*\n(?!\w+:)", r"\1 ", text, flags=re.MULTILINE)

print(text)

# A: Well hello . Long time no see . How are you doing ?
# B: Good . How are you ?
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Follow up question, how would I modify the above code if I had multiple lines between speakers? For example, line1 = A:, line2: text, line3 = text, line 4 = text, line5 = B:, line6 = text.

Comment: I added an example to the question above.

Comment: @b222 what do you want the outcome in that case to be? The code above will still work, or do you want it to have A: A: A: on each line?

Comment: I updated the example above. I'm trying to get all sentences on the same line. So continue to pull up to new line until new speaker label.

Comment: Many many thanks, jdaz. What is the rationale of first matching any character with `(.*?)` and then and whitespace character `\s*` and then the new-line feed `\n` all prior to the actual character and colon `(?!/w+:)`? 
Related, why are there no parentheses around `\s*\n` and maybe an easier question... do you have a go-to resource for learning these? I really want to get this down but find is so confusing to implement on my own. I typically have used regex101 to debug but struggle building them.

Comment: You are welcome! All I used to learn these was the Python `re` module [doc page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), regex101, and lots of practice. The `(.*?)\s*` is just to remove blank spaces at the end of each line, since they will be replaced by the space in the replacement string `"\1 "`. If you remove the question mark and `\s*` you’ll see there are extra spaces between most of the sentences, but it’s not necessary if you know your lines don’t have trailing spaces like that. `\s*\n` are outside parentheses because we want to replace them, not save them.

Answer (score 1):

If phrases are on one line this should work:

```
lines = file.readlines()
for ii in range(1,len(lines),2):
    print(lines[ii-1][:-1]+lines[ii])
```